# How to set up properly api call to search currencies with specified by user currency

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I've got stuck with declaring the retrofit call from api. I'd want to display list of currencies with their values in EUR for first (EUR is just stock currency), then I'd like to have an spinner, which should display user avaivable currencies, and then, whenever user click on some currency, let's say in USD, program should create  new call, with base currency changed from EUR to USD

This is my api call

```
@GET("latest?base={key}")
Call<Model> getRatesByGivenCurrency(@Path("key") String base);
```

how I should setup the syntax in it to have properly call? I'm just retrofit, and https://exchangeratesapi.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use from `@Query` instead of `@Path`

change the method to:

```
@GET("latest")
Call<Model> getRatesByGivenCurrency(@Query("base") String base);
```

for more detail see [link](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)